# How to get info of a non-existent file from System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception

Tags: c#, .net, winapi

I use a 3rd party library in my C# project. It throws the following exception:

> 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' occurred in System.dll but was not handled in user code
> Additional information: the system cannot find the file specified.

I wonder, for my debugging, how could I find out which file it refers to? I have checked all the properties of `Win32Exception`, but no gain.

Could anyone give me some advice?

Comment: You can use procmon from sysinternals to monitor for all file accesses (you can filter by calling process). You should see the "name not found" error.

Comment: There is no way to get the actual filename from `Win32Exception`, because the OS simply does not report that info when the error occurs. So you have to look at external sources, like ProcMon, to find out which file is failing.

Comment: Thanks @SimonMourier, I would investigate the tool mentioned.